# use table view or A view and three Subview or use labels

Tags: iphone, ios

i am a new Programmer....so i wants to know... what i use (table view,

or view and three subviews, or i use labels for it)

for generate this view on button click.... i do everything programatically...

```
CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320); //define size and position of view 
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct]; //initilize the view    
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,80,312,325) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[table setDataSource:self];
[table setDelegate:self];
```

i am confused...:(

thanks in advance

[image: this is view which comes on button(view Details) click]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Wolfert i wants view like the above image..... on button click... please advice me...what i use (table view, or subviews) for that kind of final view...

Comment: @Wolfert is this is a table view with three rows(cells with different height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a TableView with 3 different kind of subclassed UITableViewCells. This is alot of work so I can't just give you the code to do this. Instead I'll give a summary on which steps to take.

In short, to replicate this you'll need to:

1. Make 3 different UITableViewCell subclasses.
   For exmaple the first contains 7 UILabels and an UIImageView.
2. Make a UITableView class which loads these 3 cells. Basicly like this,

   - (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if (indexPath.row == 0) return cell1;
     else if (indexPath.row == 1) return cell2;
     else  return cell3;
     }
3. Set variable rowHeights via this method:

   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
4. Set the tableview properties to have a UIImage as background + set border color. Also note that the tableviewstyle is grouped.

Alternatively you could create some images in photoshop and add the labels. Much easier but not very dynamic at all.

Comment: @Wolfert.... thanks alot for giving your value-able time.... this one is perfect answer..for me.... i am trying it...thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you wanna get. If the view is fixed size is a lot easyer have it as subview, with proper background image, labels, buttons...
But if you can have more than the shown 3 "rows" table view with different custom cells is probably more flexible.